# SQL: how to select single record for multiple id's on the basis of max datetime?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, join, greatest-n-per-group

I have the following SQL table,

```
Id      WindSpeed      DateTime
--------------------------------------
1       1.1            2009-09-14 16:11:38.383
1       1.9            2009-09-15 16:11:38.383
1       2.0            2009-09-16 16:11:38.383
1       1.8            2009-09-17 16:11:38.383
1       1.7            2009-09-19 16:11:38.382
2       1.9            2009-09-19 16:11:38.383
1       1.6            2009-09-19 16:11:38.383
2       1.2            2009-09-20 16:11:38.383
```

I want to write a query which will return me the following result set from the above table:

```
Id      WindSpeed      DateTime
--------------------------------------
1       1.6            2009-09-19 16:11:38.383
2       1.2            2009-09-20 16:11:38.383
```

The above reuslt contains the latest (on the basis of latest datetime for that id) single entry. Which means I have multiple record id's with datetime.

I want to get the latest single entry of all id's.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
SELECT        a.Id, a.WindSpeed, a.DateTime
FROM          YourTable AS a
INNER JOIN     
(
    SELECT    ID, Max(DateTime) AS DateTime
    FROM      YourTable
    GROUP BY  ID
) AS b
ON            a.ID = b.ID
AND           a.DateTime = b.DateTime
```

Answer (score 5):

```
SELECT t1.Id, t1.WindSpeed, t1.DateTime
  FROM table1 As t1
 WHERE t1.DateTime = (SELECT Max(DateTime)
                       FROM table1 As t2
                      WHERE t2.ID = t1.ID)
```

Comment: Seems fine, but please edit `WHERE a.DateTime = (SELECT Max(DateTime)` line to `WHERE t1.DateTime = (SELECT Max(DateTime)`

Answer (score 2):

This should also do what you want:

```
SELECT ID, WindSpeed, [DateTime] 
FROM (
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY [DateTime] DESC) AS RowNumber,
        Id, WindSpeed, [DateTime]
    FROM MyTable
) T
WHERE RowNumber = 1
```