# Get single record id in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
    SELECT *  FROM st_master_seed_crop_dtls m 
    WHERE m.mast_sdcd_crop_category IN
    ('Notified Variety','comarket','Imported','Private Variety','Storage','Transgenic Variety') AND mast_sdcd_crop_category='Private Variety' and mast_sdcd_license_id_fk=52855
    GROUP BY m.mast_sdcd_license_id_fk
    HAVING COUNT(m.mast_sdcd_crop_category) <=1;
```

Result :

```
"49329" "52855" "16"    "114"   "Private Variety"   "ryry"  \N  "N" "Trial" \N
"49330" "52855" "5"     "38"    "Transgenic Variety"    "tyrt"  \N  "N" "Trial"
```

But I want: single record ids only.

Comment: `TOP 1` and an `ORDER BY`? You need to clarify what you're after here. A SQL statement and an image does not make a question. Thanks

Comment: Sample data is not clear. Also add expected output.

Comment: This query will result in an error in sql server because of faulty `group by`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL: how to select single record for multiple id's on the basis of max datetime?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1594092/sql-how-to-select-single-record-for-multiple-ids-on-the-basis-of-max-datetime)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this below script-

```
SELECT *
FROM st_master_seed_crop_dtls
WHERE mast_sdcd_license_id_fk IN
(
    SELECT m.mast_sdcd_license_id_fk
    FROM st_master_seed_crop_dtls m
    WHERE m.mast_sdcd_crop_category IN('Notified Variety', 'comarket', 'Imported', 'Private Variety', 'Storage', 'Transgenic Variety')
    AND mast_sdcd_crop_category = 'Private Variety'
    GROUP BY m.mast_sdcd_license_id_fk
    HAVING COUNT(m.mast_sdcd_crop_category) = 1
);
```